# SQL Query to count sessions without repeating lines

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which join themselves by a field called `user_id`. The first table called `sessions` can have multiple lines for the same day. I'm trying to find a way of selecting the total of that sessions without repeating the days (sort of).

Example:

```
Table sessions
ID | user_id | datestart
1      1        2014-08-05
2      1        2014-08-05
3      2        2014-08-05
```

As you can see there are two lines that are repeated (the first and second). If I query `SELECT COUNT(sess.id) AS total` this will retrieve `3`, but I want it to retrieve `2` because the first two lines have the same `user_id` so it must count as one.

Using the clause `Group By` will retrieve two different lines: `2` and `1`, which is also incorrect.

You can view a full example working at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89471/2).

Is there anyway of solving this only by query or do I need to do it by language?

Comment: +1 because You've prepared sql fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct sess.user_id) AS total
FROM sessions AS sess
INNER JOIN users AS user ON user.id = sess.user_id
WHERE user.equipment_id = 1 AND sess.datestart = CURDATE()
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89471/11/0)**

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) AS total
FROM sessions sess INNER JOIN
     users user
     ON user.id = sess.user_id
WHERE user.equipment_id = 1 AND
      sess.datestart = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want the number of users with sessions, rather than number of unique sessions. Use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM sessions,users WHERE user_id=users.id
```